# Style in my jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How would I style my `<ul>` in this code,

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }
});
```

I believe I can put my custom style in my `<ul>` tag but how would I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `ul.css( your css here )` not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just inspect the element in firefox you can see what style it is, then create a style for it.  Otherwise, you can use `$(element).css()`.  Ref.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Call .css() or .addClass() on your passed in ul element

If already jQuery object

```
ul.css("color", "red");
```

Otherwise make a jQuery object so you can call .css()

```
$(ul).css({ color: "red", margin: 0 });
```